# How to delete a sub collection item in Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I' am working on an angular project with `Google Cloud Firestore`. Then I have a question. How delete a sub collection item. For Example I want to delete address in follow. I'm using the `ng2-smart-table` as my table. I had added it into `manufacture` component.

**manufacture.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Manufacture } from './manufacture.model';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ManufactureService {
    manufacture: Manufacture;

    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {}

    addManufacture(object) {
        return from(
        this.firestore
            .collection('Manufacture')
            .doc('manufacture')
            .set(object)
        );
    }

    getManufacture() {
        return this.firestore
        .collection('Manufacture')
        .doc('manufacture')
        .snapshotChanges();
    }

    deleteManufacture() {
        this.firestore
        .collection('Manufacture')
        .doc('manufacture')
        .delete();      
    }

    show() {
        return this.firestore
        .collection('Manufacture')
        .doc('manufacture')
        .collection('manufact')
        .doc('0')
        .snapshotChanges();
    }
}
```

**manufacture.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ManufactureService } from './manufacture.service';
import { Manufacture } from './manufacture.model';

@Component({
selector: 'ngx-manufacture',
styles: [],
template: `
    <ng2-smart-table
    (createConfirm)="addData($event)"
    (deleteConfirm)="deleteData($event)"
    [settings]="settings"
    [source]="manu"
    >
    </ng2-smart-table>
`
})
export class ManufactureComponent implements OnInit {
    manu: Manufacture[] = [];

    constructor(private service: ManufactureService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getManufacture().subscribe(arr => {
        let manu_list = arr.payload.get('manufact');
        if (manu_list) {
            this.manu = manu_list;
        }
        });
    }

    settings = {
        add: {
        addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
        createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
        cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
        confirmCreate: true
        },
        edit: {
        editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
        saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
        cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>'
        },
        delete: {
        deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
        confirmDelete: true
        },
        columns: {
        shopname: {
            title: 'Shop Name'
        },
        ownername: {
            title: 'Owner Name'
        },
        nic: {
            title: 'NIC'
        },
        contactno: {
            title: 'ContactNo'
        },
        address: {
            title: 'Address'
        },
        email: {
            title: 'Email'
        }
        }
    };

    addData(data) {
        alert(data.newData.email);
        this.manu.push(data.newData);
        console.log(this.manu);
        this.service.addManufacture({ manufact: this.manu }).subscribe(next => {
        data.confirm.reject();
        });
    }

    deleteData(data) {
        alert(data.emial);
        this.service.deleteManufacture();
    }
}
```

[image]

Then How I do This. Once I tried by following code. but not success

```
deleteManufacture() {
     this.firestore
    .collection('Manufacture')
    .doc('manufacture')
    .delete();      
}
```

Anyone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update you object using "dot-notation".

I believe it would be something like this:

```
db.collection('Manufacture').doc('manufacture').update({
  "0.address": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
});
```

The FieldValue is a sentinel value, that is, it is used to indicate something, in this case, that we want to delete the field "0.address".

As pointed in the documentation, it is "Sentinel values that can be used when writing document fields with set() or update().". So you can use it to indicate what you intend to do with the field in `set` or `update` operations. More specific, the `delete` marks a field for deletion. There are also others such as `increment` or  `serverTimestamp`.

[Dot-operator google-cloud-firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects)

[FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FieldValue.html#delete)

Comment: what is `FieldValue`

Comment: Added more details on the answer, let me know if it is well explained now.

Comment: Sorry Sir I'm apology from you. i make a mistake while describe the question. I will reform it as soon as possible.